# degree of associative algebra

Tags: polynomials, associative-algebras

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional associative algebra with unity over a field $F$. The degree of the algebra is the degree of its generic minimum polynomial  (see Nathan Jacobson, Generic norm of an algebra, Osaka Math. J.Volume 15, Number 1 (1963), 25-50. https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ojm/1200690754  ).  If the degree of the algebra is equal to the dimension (as $F$-vector space) of the algebra $A$, can we conclude that $A\simeq F_1\times \dots \times F_n$, where $F_i$ are finite field extensions of F?

Comment: What about finite field extensions?  Are you assuming that $F$ is algebraically closed?